# Maximum timeout for java procedure call statement

Tags: java, stored-procedures, jdbc, sap-ase

I have a sybase procedure which is called from a java method. There are nearly 10000 records which would be effected by the procedure. When I call the procedure directly using a DB tool, all the records got processed successfully. But when I try to call the same procedure from java method, 2000 records are being processed at a time.

Please bail me out from this situation.

Comment: You most probably have the row count limit set to 2000 in Java somewhere.

Comment: No 2000 is an arbitrary number.. it varies from 2000 to 5000